# Can't reply to answer

Tags: support

I haven't accumulated enough points on joomla to be able to reply to another users answer, even though I have been a StackExchange member for years.

Can you please bump my reputation so that I can?

Comment: Hi JimR, I feel your pain. Myself, I don't have enough points to update tags at this time, which I found frustrating. But we have to respect the system that is in place, so I hope that you don't get discouraged, but continue to grow your reputation within the accepted ways - it's well worth it :-).

Answer (score 4):

You won't be able to leave a comment on another user's answer until you've earned **50** reputation, as stated here:

https://joomla.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment

Being able to comment on other answer is a priviledge, thus you must earn the required reputation before being able to do so. Moderators cannot bump your reputation in any way to give you access to this feature.

You'll need to continue posting/answering questions in the mean time

Comment: ...also, there are rep point rewards for significantly editing questions and answers.  If your suggested edits are deemed beneficial / "good enough" by other volunteers, they will agree to approve your efforts and you will receive 2 rep points each time.